# Azure Remote debugging vs2015 support

Tags: azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2015, azure-debugger

I've tried to set up the remote debugger for Azure Websites, Azure websites only seem to support remote debugging on VS2013 or VS2012, not 2015.

Is there a way to work around this issue?
[image: Error message returned by VS2015]

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have the latest VS2015 and SDK and try it from time to time. The plan is obviously to support VS2015 too, but please keep in mind that until there is the release version of VS, things might get broken from time to time. Basically there has to be a client version and server version of this aligned and in the preview versions it might happen that they are not backwards compatible and they get out of sync.

Unfortunately, there is not much you can do about it at this moment. If you need this for your business, I would recommend to use VS2013, which you can have installed side by side along with VS2015 Preview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there an ETA for support?

Comment: Once VS2015 is officially released (not a preview/release candidate), Azure Web Apps should be aligned as well.

Comment: This issue is still present even after vs2015 release